# How to append a value to a bytearray?

Tags: python

```
x=[12,23,36,48] 
z=bytearray(x)
z.append(13)
>>> z
bytearray(b'\x0c\x17$0\r').
```

I want to append a value in bytearray. It's not given me error but not showing the required result. 
Please help me out.

Comment: What's the expected result?

Comment: It's working fine. The display is just unintuitive.

Comment: `\r` _is_ the required result if you append 13.

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please [mark it as 'accepted’](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 1):

The code is working fine.

If you expect to see the representation of z as a list of integer numbers, convert it to `list`:

```
>>> x=[12,23,36,48]
>>> z=bytearray(x)
>>> z.append(13)
>>> z
bytearray(b'\x0c\x17$0\r')
>>> list(z)
[12, 23, 36, 48, 13]
```

Note that you don't need to convert to list to work with it.

Similar to the `append` method, the `__getitem__` method will return an integer already:

```
>>> z[0], z[1], z[2], z[3], z[4]
(12, 23, 36, 48, 13)
```

Slices however will be `bytearrays`:

```
>>> z[0:4]
bytearray(b'\x0c\x17$0')
```